# Creating Data Type table

Tags: mysql

I am new at SQL and am having a little of trouble

**This is my code**

```
CREATE TABLE dataType(
    Charater CHAR(250),
    VariaChar VARCHAR(250),
    STRING TEXT,
    interger INT(50),
    Floating FLOAT(50, 3),
    fractions DECIMAL(50, 3),
    today DATETIME("2018-10-07 12:55:20"),
    watch TIME("12:55:20"),
    centry YEAR(2018)
);
```

Basically, I am trying to make a table that has three type of text data, number data, and date data. The problem is when I run the code I get this error:

> Error SQL query:
>
> CREATE TABLE dataType(
>       Charater CHAR(250),
>       VariaChar VARCHAR(250),
>       STRING TEXT,
>       interger INT(50),
>       Floating FLOAT(50, 3),
>       fractions DECIMAL(50, 3),
>       today DATETIME("2018-10-07 12:55:20"),
>       watch TIME("12:55:20"),
>       centry YEAR(2018) )
>   
> MySQL said:
>
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '"2018-10-07 12:55:20"),
>       watch TIME("12:55:20"),
>       centry YEAR(2018) 
> )' at line 8*

***I do not know what may be causing this problem. Thank you for thanking your time to try to assist me even if this has an obvious solution.***

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/creating-tables.html&ved=2ahUKEwj65pKRyPPdAhUDH6wKHSvFCQAQFjAAegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw3lfA7dqyBvZC1otm4yG4VF

Comment: What are you trying to do with this table ultimately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DATETIME` instead of `DATETIME("2018-10-07 12:55:20")`,if you want to set the default value of `today`,you need to use `default`

```
CREATE TABLE dataType(
    Charater CHAR(250),
    VariaChar VARCHAR(250),
    STRING TEXT,
    interger INT(50),
    Floating FLOAT(50, 3),
    fractions DECIMAL(50, 3),
    today DATETIME,
    watch TIME,
    centry YEAR
);
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! I thought that you had to add value to datetime, time, and year but you do not. Thanks for giving me a straight forward answer!!

Answer (score 2):

Your default syntax is off.  Assuming you are using MySQL 5.6.5 or later, the following should work:

```
CREATE TABLE dataType(
    Charater CHAR(250),
    VariaChar VARCHAR(250),
    STRING TEXT,
    interger INT(50),
    Floating FLOAT(50, 3),
    fractions DECIMAL(50, 3),
    today DATETIME DEFAULT '2018-10-07 12:55:20',
    watch TIME DEFAULT '12:55:20',
    centry YEAR DEFAULT 2018
);
```

If you don't want default values for the final three fields, then don't use them:

```
today DATETIME,
watch TIME,
centry YEAR
```